# LoRaWAN security: Can the Network Server generate the AppSKey?

Tags: lorawan

I am a little bit confused about the LoRaWAN security mechanism.

> The NwkSKey is used by both the network server and the end-device to
>   calculate and verify the MIC (message integrity code) of all data
>   messages to ensure data integrity.
>
> The AppSKey is an application session key specific for the end-device.
>   It is used by both the application server and the end-device to
>   encrypt and decrypt the payload field of application-specific data
>   messages

So technically the Network server does not know the AppSKey.
What I dont understand is that in the OTAA procedure, the network server responds with a Join-accept that is encrypted using the AppKey. So if the network server has already the AppKey, it can generate the AppSKey using this formula:

> AppSKey = aes128_encrypt(AppKey, 0x02 | AppNonce | NetID | DevNonce | pad16)

In that case the network server if he would like to it can decrypt the message destinated to the application.

Is my analysis correct or I am missing something?

Thanks and best reagrds!

Comment: Same question answered here: https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/forum/t/lorawan-security-can-the-network-server-generate-the-appskey/8672

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer on the TTN forum:
https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/forum/t/lorawan-security-can-the-network-server-generate-the-appskey/8672